# How do you configure NLA for RDP in Windows Server 2012?

Tags: security, windows-server-2012

The Super User question [Is windows remote desktop secure?](https://superuser.com/questions/733598/is-windows-remote-desktop-secure) describes Network Level Authentication (NLA) and how to configure it in Windows Server 2008. Unfortunately, the GUI option to configure NLA is gone in Windows Server 2012.

How do you require NLA or limit RDP clients so that only new, higher security client connections can be established?

Comment: Do you have the RD Session Host role enabled?

Comment: You can use Powershell or the GUI (using the Server Manager). It's all explained on [the Petri website](https://www.petri.com/disable-remote-desktop-network-level-authentication-using-powershell)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Windows Server 2012 Group Policy Reference guide](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=25250):

> On Windows Server 2012 and Windows 8, Network Level Authentication is enforced by default.

While the option to enable or disable NLA has been removed from the GUI interface, it's still configurable via the Group Policy setting **Require user authentication for remote connections by using Network Level Authentication** found at `Computer\Policies\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Security`.  This setting must be applied to the server running the RDSH role.

Comment: Well if its the default....than I don't have to worry about it.  ;)  Thanks

Comment: Why I keep hearing another version that NLA is required since Windows 2008?

Answer (score 1):

It wasn't on for all of our servers. This might be because the server manager had decided to turn it off by default (presumably for the legions of pre-Windows XP SP3 users?!).

As Philippe pointed out - the dialog you want is shown in the [Petri article](https://www.petri.com/disable-remote-desktop-network-level-authentication-using-powershell).

[image]