# Why I cannot connect on RDP with UPN?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012

If I try to connect on RDP with User Principal Name (test@domaine.local) instead of Down-Level Logon Name (domaine\test), I get a login error on Windows Session.

RDP Settings:

[image: RDP settings]

Error:

[image: error]

When I click on OK to retry typing my login, the login field is autocomplete with my UPN prefixed by " \"!

Bad Autocomplete:

[image: bad autocomplete]

I can successfully connect by removing this prefix and typing my password again but why I have this issue?

NB: If I use Down-Level Logon Name, I can connect successfully.
My client computer run under Windows 10 Enterprise version 1703 and server one under Windows Server 2012.

Comment: FYI... This doesn't answer the question about the prefixed forward slash but read over and consider tightening the security on that RDP server....  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc732713(v=ws.11) ... I'm not certain if this would help with that problem or not but the login screen using this would look like this: https://i.imgur.com/XZFedp6.png .... Server 2012 Yes I know, I know.... https://superuser.com/questions/959728/how-do-you-configure-nla-for-rdp-in-windows-server-2012